# Simple Spinner array not showing up

Tags: arrays, string, android-studio, android-spinner

I try to make a simple spinner with 4 values, 
but when i start to code the line and i reach R.array.XXXXX the text array becomes red and its dont resolve

```
 package com.example.magazijnapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinnermagazijn;
    Button knop;
    String[] magazijnarray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinnermagazijn = findViewById(R.id.spinnermagazijn);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.


    }
}
```

At the end of the line u see my problem.

Comment: If you are using a hardcode array, you can do it using the String.xml and adding it as an Entry in the Spinner at the MainActivity.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**Create the array with the hardcoded values in Strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="my_array">
    <item>Option 1</item>
    <item>Option 2</item>
    <item>Option 3</item>
    <item>Option 4</item>
</string-array>
```

**Now you add it as a property in your spinner, at MainActivity.xml**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnermagazijn"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:entries="@array/my_array"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

If I get you right, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Alright, This worked for me... I indeed forgot to put the array into the entries of my spinner.
But now I was wondering what I need to add to make it a Required field.

Comment: well, since you don't have any empty option, you won't need to validate if user select something. But, you can add an empty item, which can be the first, and in the MainActivity.java, you can ask the user if the selectedItem is different that empty.